# I can not understand why not working in psql trigger update

Tags: psql

--I can not understand why not working in psql trigger update.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sklady CASCADE;
    CREATE TABLE sklady (
        nomer_sklada integer NOT NULL,
        familia_otvetsvennogo_lica varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT sklady_pk PRIMARY KEY (nomer_sklada)
        );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii (
    nomer_sklada integer NOT NULL,
    nomer_dokumenta_otgryzki serial NOT NULL,
    cod_pokypatela integer NOT NULL,
    cod_gotovogo_izdekiz integer NOT NULL,
    edinica_izmerenia varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    kolichestvo integer DEFAULT 1 CHECK(kolichestvo >= 1),
    data_otgruzki DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii_pk PRIMARY KEY (nomer_dokumenta_otgryzki)
    );


ALTER TABLE ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii ADD CONSTRAINT ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii_fk0 FOREIGN KEY (nomer_sklada) REFERENCES sklady(nomer_sklada);
```

----update----

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_triger_update() RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii SET nomer_sklada = NEW.nomer_sklada
WHERE nomer_sklada = OLD.nomer_sklada;
RETURN NEW;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_update ON sklady;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON sklady
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_triger_update();
```

----insert----

```
INSERT INTO sklady(nomer_sklada, familia_otvetsvennogo_lica) VALUES
    (0, 'first'),
    (1, 'second'),
    (2, 'thred');



INSERT INTO ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii(
            nomer_sklada, nomer_dokumenta_otgryzki, cod_pokypatela, cod_gotovogo_izdekiz, 
            edinica_izmerenia, kolichestvo, data_otgruzki) VALUES
    (0, 0, 0, 3, 'gram', 200, '2016-10-01'),
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 'kilogram', 22, '2016-10-07'),
    (1, 2, 2, 0, 'kilogram', 123, '2016-10-05'),
    (0, 3, 3, 2, 'gram', 14, '2016-10-01'),
    (2, 4, 4, 2, 'gram', 14, '2016-10-01'),
    (2, 5, 5, 4, 'gram', 199, '2016-11-22');

UPDATE sklady SET nomer_sklada = 3 WHERE nomer_sklada = 0;
```

error:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii" violates foreign key constraint "ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii_fk0"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (nomer_sklada)=(3) is not present in table "sklady".
>
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii SET nomer_sklada = NEW.nomer_sklada
>       WHERE nomer_sklada = OLD.nomer_sklada"
>       PL/pgSQL function func_triger_update() line 3 at SQL statement

Comment: I can not understand what not working in psql Triger updata

Comment: UPDATE sklady SET nomer_sklada = 3 WHERE nomer_sklada = 0;

ERROR:  insert or update on table "ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii" violates foreign key constraint "ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii_fk0"
DETAIL:  Key (nomer_sklada)=(3) is not present in table "sklady".
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii SET nomer_sklada = NEW.nomer_sklada
WHERE nomer_sklada = OLD.nomer_sklada"
PL/pgSQL function func_triger_update() line 3 at SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

you have a foreign key **ythet_otgruzki_gotovoq_produkcii_fk0** which resticts setting the value of nomer_sklada to **3**, because this column references table **sklady**, same column name. This is written in error details:

> DETAIL: Key (nomer_sklada)=(3) is not present in table "sklady".

If you run smth like

```
INSERT INTO sklady(nomer_sklada, familia_otvetsvennogo_lica) VALUES (3,'chetvertyj');
```

quoted update won't rise an error